# Compute range between datetimes in SQL Server 2005 - but only count within specified bounds

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

In SQL Server 2005 I have this requirement where I get start and end date for some activity.

Also, in a day there are two time slots like from 5 am till 9 am and from 2 pm till 6 pm, I need to find out how many minutes this start and end date falls within these time slots.

For example if start is 24-01-2014 6:30 am and end is other day i.e. 25-01-2014 11 am. This the result should be for 24th 9 am - 6:30 so 150 mins and full slot in the evening so 240 mins full slot the next morning so 240 mins

Total = 150 + 240 + 240.

I am trying to write a function and use that within my query. I will be passing start and end dates to my function.

Any help is appreciated.

I have started writing code but it has sooo many conditions so I thought better to seek advice from someone who knows more SQL than me.

Let me try to explain better.

I have two dates one is start date and other is end date and both have time.

Now in a day there are two time periods in which I am interested in and want to find out how many minutes fall under these time ranges between these two dates.

So if time slots per day are 5 till 9 am and 16 to 20 pm.

How many minutes of these two slots my start and end dates come under?

So if start date is 24/01/2014 6:30 and end date is 24/01/2014 17:30.

So these two dates use 9 - 6:30 so 2 hours and 30 minutes from first time slot of 5 to 9 am and 17:30 - 16:00 = 1 hour and 30 minutes from the second slot.

These start and end dates can be any dates either of the same day or end can be the next day or n number of days after that.

Comment: I'm really not clear on how you arrive at your solution - could you please explain your algorithm and desired output more clearly?

Comment: Hello user3230006. Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to get help faster (and strictly to the point) please work with us to make your question clear: First, show us some code! What have you tried? What do you envision as your function signature? What are the expected results?

Comment: Sorry - I should have said Welcome too! I didn't see this was your first post.

Comment: I have started writing code but it has sooo many conditions so I thought better to seek advice from someone who knows more sql than me.

Let me try to explain better.

I have two dates one is start date and other is end date and both have time.

Now in a day there are two time periods in which I am interested in and want to find out how many minutes fall under these time ranges between these two dates.

So if time slots per day are 5 till 9 am and 16 to 20 pm.

Comment: How many minutes of these two slots my start and end dates come under?


so if start date is 24/01/2014 6:30 and end date is 24/01/2014 17:30.

So theese two dates use 9 - 6:30 so 2 hours and 30 minutes from first time slot of 5 to 9 am and 17:30 - 16:00 = 1 hour and 30 minutes from the second slot.

These start and end dates can be any dates either of the same day or end can be the next day or n number of days after that.

Comment: I got you. Might want to delete your extra comments here. I'm working on something, tell me - do you care about fractional minutes?

Comment: No I don't care about fractional minutes, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've prepared two User-defined scalar value functions that work with the lack of DateTime functionality provided in SQL Server 2005. Note that all fractional minutes are truncated (e.g. 00:59:59 will be chopped to 59 minutes).

The basic premise is that we are shifting the time domain to only factor in the minutes that you care about.

#### Tests

```
select dbo.fnDateDiff_SigMinutes('2014-01-24 6:30 AM', '2014-01-24 11:00 AM')  --returns 150
select dbo.fnDateDiff_SigMinutes('2014-01-24 6:30 AM', '2014-01-26 11:00 AM')  --returns 1110
select dbo.fnDateDiff_SigMinutes('2014-01-24 6:30 AM', '2014-01-25 11:00 AM')  --returns 630
select dbo.fnDateDiff_SigMinutes('2014-01-24 6:30 AM', '2014-01-25 5:00 PM')   --returns 810
select dbo.fnDateDiff_SigMinutes('2014-01-24 11:00 AM', '2014-01-27 5:00 PM')  --returns 1620
select dbo.fnDateDiff_SigMinutes('2014-01-24 11:00 AM', '2014-01-27 5:00 AM')  --returns 1200
```

#### dbo.fnDateDiff_SigMinutes

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnDateDiff_SigMinutes](@DateBegin datetime, @DateEnd datetime)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @diff int

--Figure out if the two dates are on the same actual day.
DECLARE @dateOnly_start datetime, @dateOnly_end datetime
select @dateOnly_start = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @DateBegin))
select @dateOnly_end = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @DateEnd))

IF @dateOnly_start = @dateOnly_end
begin
    --figure out our minutes
    declare @minuteBegin int, @minuteEnd int
    select @minuteBegin = dbo.fnGetSigMinutes(@DateBegin)
    select @minuteEnd = dbo.fnGetSigMinutes(@DateEnd)

    select @diff = @minuteEnd - @minuteBegin

end
else
begin
--compute the number of days between the two, multiply result by 480
select @diff = (datediff(day, @DateBegin, @DateEnd)) * 480

if (@diff = 0)
    --compute difference between midnight and start, end and midnight
    select @diff = @diff + dbo.fnDateDiff_SigMinutes(@DateBegin, dateadd(minute, 1439, @dateOnly_start))
                         + dbo.fnDateDiff_SigMinutes(@dateOnly_end, @DateEnd)
else
    select @diff = @diff + dbo.fnDateDiff_SigMinutes(@DateBegin, dateadd(day, datediff(day, @DateEnd, @DateBegin), @DateEnd))
end

return @diff

END
```

#### dbo.fnGetSigMinutes

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetSigMinutes](@date DateTime)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

/*
Minutes 0-300 do not count
Minutes 300-540 count
Minutes 540-840 do not count
Minutes 840-1080 count
Minutes 1080-1440 do not count

Therefore, you can shift the minute of the day into a your chosen domain using a stepwise transform:
*/
declare @m int,  @ma int  --minute (m), minute_adjusted (ma)
select @m = datediff(minute, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @date)), @date)
select @ma = 
case when (@m < 300) then 0
     when (@m < 540) then @m - 300
     when (@m < 840) then 240
     when (@m < 1080) then @m - 600 
     else 480
end

return @ma

END
```

Comment: Hi, wow this looks really good, just one question, What does this line do? --compute the number of whole days between the two, multiply result by 480....Why multiple by 480?

Comment: Ha! I just realized there was some test code in there that needed to get switched out. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks, I am just trying to understand your code, if I want to change the timeslots from 5 to 9 and 15 to 20 (instead of 16 to 20) do I change the case values accordingly?

Comment: Also this one select dbo.fnDateDiff_SigMinutes('2014-01-24 6:30 AM', '2014-01-26 11:00 AM') returns 2550? Am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: Sorry but its not working as per the examples you have given either.

Comment: I'll look at it tomorrow. Stand by.

Comment: Now it is, I needed to re-think the second half of the if-statement (for the case when the dates are different). Works now.

Answer (score 1):

A small improvement.
I respect  mayer06  for the analysis and hard work and problem solving.
And feel that the first function might be streamlined --

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnDateDiff_SigMinutes](@DateBegin datetime, @DateEnd datetime)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @diff int

--Figure out if the elapsed days between two dates w/o times, and multiply by 480.
DECLARE @dateOnly_start datetime, @dateOnly_end datetime
select @dateOnly_start = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @DateBegin))
select @dateOnly_end = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @DateEnd))
select @diff = (datediff(day, @DateBegin, @DateEnd)) * 480

--figure out our minutes
declare @minuteBegin int, @minuteEnd int
select @minuteBegin = dbo.fnGetSigMinutes(@DateBegin)
select @minuteEnd = dbo.fnGetSigMinutes(@DateEnd)

-- compute the total difference
select @diff = @diff + @minuteEnd - @minuteBegin


return @diff

END
```

with due credits to  mayer06   for the original solution.

Comment: Upvote - I realized after I did the thing that this could be done- but should have applied it as you have. That's what happens when you are up really late.

Comment: Hi mayer06, I had been doing CYA parallel dev in MSAccess while you were fixing your code, and stood by ready to rescue. But you solved the problems... I would replace 480 with Declare MinPerDay and then have a Select MinPerDay = dbo.fnGetSigMinutes("11:59:59 PM") and keep all the ShiftDurations in the lower level function.  Requestor is contemplating changing Start/End, and perhaps number of Shifts...   Also, more comments in fnGetSigMinutes to relate Minutes to time...e.g.   --300 = 5:00 AM . Otherwise, GREAT

Comment: Thanks Mayer and Don for helping me with this.